# Why is php's fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) only grabbing the first column of my table?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

The following code is a section of one of my classes:

```
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM checkOut WHERE t_id = :param1");             
        $stmt->bindParam(':param1', $this->numberIn);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($result);
        $this->p_id = $result['p_id'];
```

My original issue was that php was stating that `p_id` was an undefined index. To figure out what was going on, I threw in `var_dump` to see what was in the array. For some reason, it contained only one value, `4` which corresponded to the first column's name, `t_id`. My MySQL table has four columns, and I need all four to be present in the array. Why would my code only be grabbing the first column's value?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only fetching one field:

```
SELECT t_id FROM checkOut ...
       ^^^^
```

if you want p_id, then you'll have to fetch that too:

```
SELECT p_id, t_id FROM checkOut
```

Comment: That's interesting. I was expecting that my query would locate the row associated with my parameter, so when I use fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) it would grab the entire row where t_id=whatever. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: Nope. if you don't explicitly request a field (or at least use `select *`), then you don't get other fields. It's a waste of disk bandwidth, cpu time, etc... to fetch data needlessly, so the db server won't get anything you don't ask for.

Answer (score 1):

You use `SELECT t_id`. Use `SELECT *` instead.